What permission is needed to read sys.dm_db_stats_properties?
Using Azure SQL, I have a procedure signed by certificate in which I'd like to read table statistics. The proc can read sys.stats fine but I get zero rows from a query using sys.dm_db_stats_properties, for example FROM sys.stats S CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties(S.object_id,S.stats_id) SP  WHERE S.object_id= 123456.
I have applied the following perms to the user that the cert is linked to...
GRANT VIEW PERFORMANCE DEFINITION TO Maintenance_User
GRANT VIEW DATABASE PERFORMANCE STATE TO Maintenance_User
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO Maintenance_User
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO Maintenance_User
Am I missing another GRANT? Is there a different permission I need to apply?

According to Microsoft, in order to view the statistics object, the user must own the table, or the user must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role.
In addition, the documentation for sys.dm_db_stats_properties (emphasis added) says:

Requires that the user has select permissions on statistics columns or the user owns the table or the user is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role.

